# Difference between apt command and sudo apt command in Linux Mint terminal?

Tags: apt

I was wondering what the difference was between the two because both of them seem to work when doing stuff. Command is a placeholder name for upgrade, update or install or whatever.

Does it matter which one I use?

I am running Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: You need `sudo` to run most `apt` commands unless you are making the mistake of logging in as root. Could you [edit] your question and add some specific `apt` commands that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt is a package manager for debian branch.
You cannot install package without behind root (su) or having that powers (sudo)
But, you can search for example `apt-cache search <package>` without being root.
To install you must be root (su) or have its power

```
sudo apt-get install <packages-name>
```

To understand how apt works

```
man apt
```

Comment: So if I was a secondary user I would have to use sudo? Is that what you mean? I am the owner and I can use either, I just have to put in the password each time I re-open the terminal.

Comment: You can be a primary user and have sudo installed.

Comment: sudo mean you have root power, but, you stay the user.

Comment: I mean, does it matter which one I use?

Comment: 'cd' command will bring you to your user directory /home/you rather than if you where # root that would bring you to the /root/ directory

Comment: the point is that when you install a software that will affect some / (root) directories, so that is why you need to have that power (su or sudo)

Comment: rather than a simple search that have no effect on the / (root) that is why we call root user the root because he have full access to the / (root)

Comment: exact, in that type of situation you just need to have the root power, no care you use su or sudo.

Comment: So because I am the owner I can skip writing sudo all the time?

Comment: Yes, the point is that sudo offer you different interest in edition ... a sudo vim is more easy than log as root then unlog, log .. unlog.